# How to get passed parameter of Json_encoded using php

Tags: php, arrays, json, sqlite

I am passing a parameter to a php url. For example, `name.local.test/api.php?id=5&name=test`. I was then getting the data from the url using the GET method and was saving it into a mysqlite database. After saving I am displaying the saved data with Json_encoded format.

```
[{"time":"1561384655","ip":"192.168.103.151","waterlevel":"85","station":"Near the Training Center","humidity":"39","temperature":"26"}
```

what is the easiest way to print such values in the json format on php page?

I am expecting something like:

> 

```js
function getData() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
     //Push the data in array
  var time = new Date().toLocaleTimeString();
  var txt = this.responseText;
  var obj = JSON.parse(txt); //Ref: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp
      ADCvalues.push(obj.waterlevel);
      Tvalues.push(obj.temperature);
      Hvalues.push(obj.humidity);
      timeStamp.push(time);
      showGraph();  //Update Graphs
  //Update Data Table
    var table = document.getElementById("dataTable");
    var row = table.insertRow(1); //Add after headings
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
    var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
    cell1.innerHTML = time;
    cell2.innerHTML = obj.waterlevel;
    cell3.innerHTML = obj.temperature;
    cell4.innerHTML = obj.humidity;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "http://abdikani.local.abaarsoschool.org/json.php", true); //Handle readADC server on ESP8266
  xhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: If it's in JSON, that means it's a string. Just do `echo $json_string;`

Comment: It is on a different page not on the same page

Comment: You can try to send the data over a `$_SESSION` variable, or a `$_GET` variable, or a `$_POST` variable. Or you can pull it from your database again.

Comment: Why dont you load the data, json_ecode it and echo it on the other page?